# python, finding duplicates

Tags: python, csv, duplicates

the first code is returning 5021 lines where are second code is giving only 2507. can anyone tell me why? I am trying to find duplicates.

Code 1:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as f_out:
    with open('org2fsjapan.txt', encoding = 'utf-8') as jap:
        a = jap.readline()
        f_out.write(a)
        for lines in jap:
            a = lines.find('1000190522')
            if not a == -1:   
                f_out.write(lines)
```

Code 2:

```
with open('output.txt','w') as f:

    with open('org2fsjapan.txt', encoding = 'utf-8') as jap:
        for lines in jap:
            lines = jap.readline()
            a = lines.find('1000190522')
            if not a == -1:
                xl = lines.split('|^|')
                f.write(xl[0]+','+xl[5]+'\n')
```

Comment: In code2, Print ```lines``` after the for statement then after the ```lines = ....``` statement.  Looks like you are reading two lines each iteration.

Comment: Why are you checking every second line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second program, you have the following statements:

```
for lines in jap:
    lines = jap.readline()
```

Both the for loop and the call to readline() read a line from the file referenced by jap, so you're reading two lines on each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that you have an extra `f_out.write(a)` in Code 1 right after `a = jap.readline()`. That would write the every line to the output file even if its not a match.

Comment: The readline() and first f_out.write() in his first program is only executed once, for the first line in the file.